# Get Android application package name during annotation processing

Tags: java, android, annotation-processing

I'm working on a library that generates a class file based on annotated classes and fields at compile time (when hitting build). So far everything is fine (class can be generated). However, I have a problem in how to find such a generated class when the application is launched (the class needs to be accessed within the `onCreate` method of the `Application`).

The code looks something like this:

```
- Application class of an Android app -
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    MyLib.setup(this);
}
```

And within the class `MyLib`, something like this needs to be done:

```
public void setup(Application app) {
    String className = String.format("%s.%s", "packageName", "generatedClassName");
    Class<?> myGeneratedClass = Class.forName(className);
    ...
}
```

The problem is I don't know how to find the class without knowing its package name and also don't know how to find its package name.

I could think of a way to do this is passing the package name into one of the annotation like @MyAnnotation("package_name") to use it when generating the class at compile time and obtaining that class at runtime.

However I'm just wondering if there is any other cleaner ways to achieve this. Is there any way to either:
1. Obtain the Application package name during annotation processing
2. Look for a class at runtime without knowing its package (only know the Application package). I did try `Package.getPackages()` within `MyLib.setup()`. However this returns an empty array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a well-researched issue. The simplest approach is having your users annotate the application package (yes, [annotating a package is possible](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=packaga-info.java)) or pass the name of app package via [javac parameter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javac.html#options) (android-apt and new versions of Android Gradle plugin have native support for those). This is cheap and will get you going quickly.

Getting package name heuristically is possible and AndroidAnnotations has a chunk of code for that (more precisely, for [finding AndroidManifest.xml](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/blob/7b7a55ebacb58e26988a2f8f8adf0eb6e0b56d2f/AndroidAnnotations/androidannotations-core/androidannotations/src/main/java/org/androidannotations/internal/helper/AndroidManifestFinder.java) and [locating R.java](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/blob/7b7a55ebacb58e26988a2f8f8adf0eb6e0b56d2f/AndroidAnnotations/androidannotations-core/androidannotations/src/main/java/org/androidannotations/internal/rclass/AndroidRClassFinder.java)), both of which can give out app package. Beware, those methods are not pretty. Note, that AndroidAnnotations have plugin system, so you can get access to that functionality without re-doing their work by writing a plugin and declaring dependency on their main processor.

Finally, you can write your own Gradle plugin and access this kind of information directly.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Very informative. I'm excited to find out that AndroidAnnotations have those methods. I found the plugin option very interesting. Could you please give a bit more info about it? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Override Application class

```
private static Context sContext;

    @Override
       protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
       super.attachBaseContext(base);
       sContext = base;
    }

    public static Context getAppContext() {
        return sContext;
    }
```

To get package name

```
YourApplication.getAppContext().getPackageName();
```

Edited:
To get package name of annotated element in class extended from `AbstractProcessor`
you can use this

```
final String originalPackageName = element.getEnclosingElement().toString();
```

where element is TypeElement `instance`

Comment: I know how to do this, but as I mentioned in the question, I'll need to get the package name at compile time which means somehow it must be accessed from an Annotation Processor (i.e., within the `public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnv)` function. But thanks anw

Comment: Added. Hope it can help

Comment: Yep, this can be achieved if I annotate the Application class and use it to get the package. In my case, I used annotations for another class and I was reluctant to add another annotation for the Application class just for getting its package at compile time - because this requires an additional step that a user needs to do to use the library I'm writing. I'm not sure if it's possible to do that without doing what you mentioned and what I mentioned in the question. But still want to look for another solution before I decide to take either of these 2 options.

Comment: Maybe you can do something like android annotation does. Generate new class in the same package as original class with the changed name?